# different levels of user accesses to an SQLIte Db file

Tags: database, sqlite

I know that SQLite doesn't support setting up different users. I have a requirement where I need to prevent certain set of users from doing INSERTS/UPDATES into the SQLite DB. As SQLite doesnt have any GRANT/REVOKE commands is there any other way to setup different access levels to the DB file apart changing the file permissions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not built into sqlite, no.

You could write your own access control, however.  Many web projects are an example of this model.  They regularly authenticate against user records contained within the database itself.